# Composer says ???? when trying to install

Tags: php, composer-php

I recently installed the [PHP Composer dependency manager](http://getcomposer.org), however, now when I try to run the command `php composer.phar install` it simply outputs `????`. There is a `composer.json` file in the same directory, but I can't get it to work.

The contents of my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.2.*"
    }
}
```

If I try adding `-v` to the command (`php composer.phar install -v`) like suggested in the comments, it still says the same thing.

What do I do?

Comment: Try increasing verbosity by adding -v to `php composer.phar install`

Comment: @Mantas It still just says `????`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to fix this problem with a similar solution to Mantas's below.

In his answer, you just add `detect_unicode`, but I managed to get it to work for me with this command:

```
php -d detect_unicode=Off -d suhosin.executor.include.whitelist=phar composer.phar install
```

When I installed Composer I also had to put these both in, so I guess you need to whenever you run the file...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
php -d detect_unicode=Off composer.phar install
```

Comment: When I do this nothing is displayed, and there are no new files in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

`php composer.phar diagnose`

It's a system [sanity check function](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#diagnose).   It may report your issue.

Comment: This doesn't work, it still says `????`. I think it must be something to do with PHP executing the `phar` file...